# Global web.xml conf in JBoss 7

Tags: jboss7.x

In JBoss 4.2.3 we could configure items in

[jboss_server]/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/conf/web.xml

which would be adopted by all applications deployed.  We've used this to configure context params, servlets, and default tag files.

We have dozens of apps deployed in war files, and this a very handy tool.

How is this accomplished in JBoss 7.1.1?  I've googled and searched but can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: BTW, I've also posted this question here: https://community.jboss.org/thread/217569

Comment: Is there something specific you need to be applied to all your applications? some common property or what?

Comment: We've used it to add context parameters which are adopted by all apps.  That could be done with System properties though, or environment vars.  What is a bit more complicated, is that we use it to configure a filters, as well as a servlet mapping that all apps inherit.  We used it to configure tag libraries as well (the same way the jstl tag library was included).  I think tag libraries can be included around via modules, so that leaves servlets, and filters.

Comment: 1: there is no provided way to have a global web.xml on AS7 (security concerns) 
2: Read 1 again. 
hope this helps. Sorry but that is what is true.

Comment: You can write your own deployer that will do what you want.

Comment: @MukulGoel this should be an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 0):

You could try web fragments (part of Servlet API 3.x). You'll be able to apply the same set of filters, mappings, listeners, variables to each web app's context using one META-INF/web-fragment.xml file (inside some WEB-INF/lib/my-common-context.jar, so it'd be easily managed as a simple dependency).